# How can I find an empty name using grep in bash json?

Tags: json, bash, parsing, grep

How can I find an empty name using grep?

my json files

```
{
    "IDS": [
        {
            "digest": "sha256:b97"
        },
        {
            "digest": "sha256:d25"
        },
        {
            "digest": "sha256:c40",
            "tag": "0"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'd like to use grep to find a digest file without tag.

i want to like this result.

```
sha256:b97
sha256:d25
```

I have used 'has(tag) == false' in jq, but my environmental nature is not available using jq

I wonder how to use it without jq, python and other tools.

Thank you for reading my post. XD

Comment: Unless you use/write a full-fledged JSON engine in Bash, you’re gonna need some assumptions about how the JSON file is written. Are you 100% sure that the file follows the exact structure as shown above? By structure, I mean even things like where newlines and commas are placed.

Comment: @vdavid 
yes sure! 100%, this structure shown above.
This structure is aws ecr list-images command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If jq is out of the question, an awk alternative might be:

```
awk '/"digest"[^,]+$/{gsub(/"/,""); print $NF}' input.json
```

If input is minified:

```
$ echo $foo
{ "IDS": [ { "digest": "sha256:b97" }, { "digest": "sha256:d25" }, { "digest": "sha256:c40", "tag": "0" } ] }
$
$ awk -vRS='[{}]' 'NF==2 && $0 ~ /"digest"/{gsub(/"/,"");print $NF}' <<< "$foo"
sha256:b97
sha256:d25
```

Comment: That's right, awk is a good alternative, but the command doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Then perhaps you're not using the input posted in the question?

Comment: No, I'm using that input.  json=$(echo {  "IDS": [ ... ] })

Comment: It will work if you save your input as 'input.json', and run it as shown above.

Comment: oh sorry yes this is work! XD But I need to know universally. 
(eg.  {
    "IDS": [
        {
            "digest": "sha256:b97"
        },
        {
            "digest": "sha256:d25"
        },
        {
            "digest": "sha256:c40",
            "tag": "0"
        },
        {
            "digest": "sha256:b52"
        },
        {
            "digest": "sha256:t55",
            "tag": "1"       
        },
    ]
}

Comment: greaaaaaaaaaatttttttteeeee! super hack XD, thank you @Thomas Hansen

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a regular expression for this. Use a JSON parser:

```sh
jq -r '.IDS[] | select(has("tag") | not) | .digest' file.json
```

If you're not allowed to use the right tools, your employer is not letting you do your job.

Comment: I agree, as you can see from the text, I used to use jq before.